# Unable to correctly type the firmware password on my MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, keyboard-layout, firmware

I made the mistake of setting the firmware password on my MacBook Pro, unaware that when I have to enter the password, e.g. when booting in recovery mode, the keyboard mapping is default US. When I set the password, the German keyboard layout was active. Unfortunately my password contains some special chars: "$", "ß" and "ö".

I know that I can type those keys with SHIFT+4 for "$", ALT+s for "ß" and for "ö" it should be ALT+u and then "o". But this does not work. I guess in the password mode, its probably the "ö" that is not typed correctly. I saw the similar effect when I enter a password containing the same specials chars in the shell. As a plain text I can enter the password's text using the key combinations mentioned before, but when I enter the text as a password, it is not accepted.

Any other way to enter these special chars?

Comment: How exactly do you determine you are able to type the characters in question in every field except the password field.  This sound like a question Apple support could answer.

Comment: I used the same password as I used for my admin account. When I switch to US keyboard I can not su with that password though it is shown correctly when I enter it in plain text. Switching back to German keyboard it is accepted. So I am just assuming that this is connected to the behaviour in the firmware password field. Of course, Apple support might be able to help but I hoped to find an answer here.

Comment: Might consider changing the password if you use both a German and US keyboard so it doesn't contain the special characters.

Comment: How to change it if I can not enter recovery mode? I think that can only be done in an apple shop which I try to avoid.